# How to use a variable as part of an URL

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a variable

```
var qstAccessCode:String = "default";
```

and a loader with URLRequest

```
var qst:XML;
var qstLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
qstLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/44181313/Qaaps/Audio/" + qstAccessCode + ".qst"));
qstLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processQST);

function processQST(e:Event):void {
    qst = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace("QST loading");
}
```

I would like to use the value of *qstAccessCode* to complete the URL (so I can change the URL based on user input - if no input then use "default") but I get an error:

"1120: Access of undefined property qstAccessCode"

Is this to do with scoping? How can I complete the URL? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** I haven't been able to get clear on this, so  I'm also going to look at generating the complete URL from the user-input function and see if I get the URLRequest to pick it up as a variable. If there are any further comments on the original idea I will be very grateful to read them. Cheers.

**Edit**: @Moorthy I have qstAccessCode defined like this:

```
var qatAccessCode:String = "default";
var stageText:StageText = new StageText();
stageText.returnKeyLabel = ReturnKeyLabel.GO;
stageText.stage = this.stage;
stageText.viewPort = new Rectangle(225, 765, 200, 35 );

stageText.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onChange);
function onChange(e:Event):void 
{
    qatAccessCode = stageText.text; 
    trace(qatAccessCode);
}
```

It traces keyboard entry when I test movie (Air 3.2 for Android).

Comment: Where have you defined "qstAccessCode" variable? Where have you trying to access it?

Comment: it's definitely a scoping problem :)

Comment: qstAccessCode is defined as a var in the user-input function (see updated question).

Answer (score 2):

`qstAccessCode` should be defined in the same scope as the URLRequest.

Answer (score 0):

You must defined property `qstAccessCode` like:

```
var qstAccessCode:string;
```

`qstAccessCode`'s value is your url address.